# DateTime Diff having inconsistencies in Months

Tags: php, datetime

Having a problem with difference in months, function below returns the age with month

```
function ageMonths($dob)
{
    //new date time $dob must be Y-m-d format
    $dobObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$dob);

    //current date
    $nowObject = new DateTime();

    //difference
    $diff = $nowObject->diff($dobObject);
    return $diff->y.'.'.$diff->m;
}
```

problem is i am having inconsistencies in months some are exact some are not, please look at the sample below

```
5.5 - 2008-10-03 correct
8.2 - 2005-12-27 must be 8.3
4.5 - 2009-09-24 must be 4.6
6.7 - 2007-07-14 must be 6.8
6.7 - 2007-07-17 must be 6.8
6.5 - 2007-09-28 must be 6.6
7.1 - 2007-01-17 must be 7.2
7.1 - 2007-02-10 correct
6.3 - 2007-11-16 must be 6.4
7.1 - 2007-02-10 correct
6.3 - 2007-11-16 must be 6.4
6.10 - 2007-05-08 correct
```

I cannot find what is wrong, any ideas?

Comment: @this.lau_ the values are just concatenated `{year}.'.'.{month}`

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect, php gives the right intervals: http://3v4l.org/ElnYG#v552

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no rounding going on, it's just that your notion of "months difference" is not the same as the one used by `DateInterval`.

Subtracting two `DateTime` values imbues the resulting `DateInterval` with a "months" value equal to the number of *whole* (in the calendar sense) months of difference between the dates. For example, in calendar terms 2013-03-11 is zero months away from 2013-04-01 (2013-04-11 would be one month away).

What you want is not months of difference calendar-wise, but the arithmetic difference of month indexes. For example, 2013-03-11 has a month difference of 1 from 2013-04-01 (because 4 - 3 = 1).

So, get your desired result this way:

```
$dobObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$dob);
$nowObject = new DateTime();

return $dobObject->format('n') - $nowObject->format('n'); // might be negative
```

**[See the difference live](http://ideone.com/dcHowK)**.

Answer (score -1):

2008-10-03  -> Y - m - d here m represents with leading zeros 01  through 12.
2008-10-03  -> Y - n - d here n represents without leading zeros 1 through 12.

use n for getting exact month for calculating age. cheers

Comment: -1, this is just wrong. In both cases the representation is 1 to 12, and there would be no difference even if it were not. Where did you get this information?